# How to combine several proxies into one?

Tags: networking, proxy

I've seen implementations that combine multiple network interfaces together to speed up the network performance. Is there something like that but for proxies? Notably SOCKS proxies.

If there isn't a program for that (GUI or console, I don't care), then would creating and combining several badvpn tun* interfaces work? (each having it's own IP and SOCKS proxy gateway, and tied together by dispatch proxy)